# Network is not connecting after startup automatically in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, drivers, dhcp

After some perturbations with network drivers now I have a situation where the network is not connecting automatically after the boot-up. It indicates, that the connection is limited or no connectivity. When I look into LAN status it appears as "not connected".

[image]

(Ethernet status is what it says. Previously it was "Local Area Connection status"). And the automatic wizard was unable to fix the problem.

[image]

I have to "disable" and "enable the LAN each time to get connected to the Internet. How am I support fix this, so that the client will obtain IP's through DHCP.

Comment: It's driver problem. Replace your Ethernet Driver with another one.

Answer (score 5):

Some more information that will help : Windows version, network card make and driver version. I will assume Windows 7.

**Fully patch Windows**

Call up Windows Update and install all updates, including optional ones.

**Check network driver version**

Find on the website of the manufacturer of the network card the latest driver
for the card (if available), download and install.

**Check Windows integrity**

Execute [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)
to check the integrity of all protected Windows 7 system files and replace damaged versions with the correct ones (if possible).

**Verify TCP/IP Settings**

In Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change adapter settings, right-click
the network adapter and choose Properties.

If you don't use IPv6 in your home network, uncheck Internet Protocol Version 6.

Click on Internet Protocol Version 4 and then Properties, and
ensure that both the IP and DNS server addresses are set to automatic.

Reboot.

**Reset TCP/IP**

Run the Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator and type

```
netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Reboot.

**Last measures**

If the above has not resolved the problem, try to see if it arrives when booting in Safe Mode with Network. If it does, then Windows is damaged and should be repaired.
If it does not arrive, then some installed product is responsible for the problem.

You might also consider rolling back to a system restore point dating from
before the problem occurred, if no other changes were made to Windows in that period
beside these of the network card (such as installation of new products).

Answer (score 4):

With all above said. If nothing helps.

1. Firstly, try uninstalling & re-installing the LAN driver. To do that right click **My computer** > **Manage** > select **Device manager**, under the tree you'll see **Network adapters**. Expand it & right click on the LAN adapter, uninstall it. Afterwards, right click somewhere in that tree & select **Scan for hardware changes**
2. If method 1 did not help. Try to restore your workstation to a recent earliest date where the system was working fine. Once rebooted it should work properly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a variety of symptoms that causes this problem. Can you kindly go to computer manager and then services?

1. right click 'my computer'
2. select manage
3. go to 'services & applications'
4. navigate to 'services'

Check that all the 'network' services are started, except 'network access point'. Check that the 'dhcp client service' is started automatically (this enables your pc to receive an IP).

Go to command prompt, start > run > cmd. Then do an 'IPCONFIG' before you have to disable and enable your Local area connection. Kindly paste the ipv4 part, this will help with the problem isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because it recognized it as a "Public Network". Change it to a "Private Network" and it should work!